# finding position of node in scenekit

Tags: position, transform, transformation, blender, scenekit

In order to get all my project to put everything where I wanted it, I applied a transformation of (0,0,0) to every object in blender before I exported it.  This resulted in the run scene looking exactly like the blender file, but every SCNNode giving me a position of (0,0,0) when I ask for it.  I have tried a dozen methods to try to get the right position for each object, they keep saying that the position is (0,0,0).  Any advice?

```
 var rollingBall: SCNNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 15))

    scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock(){
        node, stop in
        if node.name  == "BackWall" {
            println("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV")
            var axis: SCNVector3
            node.position = self.scene.rootNode.convertPosition(node.position, toNode: node.presentationNode())

            rollingBall.transform = node.worldTransform
            rollingBall.scale = SCNVector3Make(1,1,1)
            rollingBall.position.y = 70

            let x = rollingBall.presentationNode()
            let carPos = rollingBall.position
            let targetPos = SCNVector3Make(x.position.x, x.position.y, x.position.z + 150)
            self.cameraNode.position = targetPos
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. If no object has a transformation applied, is it not expected that they all are positioned at `(0,0,0)` ?

Comment: thats what their position says, but they are all over the scene exactly where I placed them.  I hit Ctrl A apply Location in blender so they all say their position is (0,0,0) in blender and scene kit, but I need to find where they're located in the scene

Comment: I'm not a Blender user, but it might be that Blender changes the position of the geometry's vertices so that the node position is 0